# How to run a setuid program on Solaris 10?

Tags: solaris, setuid

I have a Solaris 10 system:

```
# uname -a
SunOS edddev03 5.10 Generic_150400-04 sun4v sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5120
```

I wrote a program printing the uid:

```
# cat getuid.c
int main (void) {
  printf ("%d\n", getuid());
}
```

It works as expected:

```
# gcc -o /bin/getuid getuid.c
# getuid
0
# su nobody -c /bin/getuid
60001
```

Now I changed it to be a setuid program:

```
# chmod 4555 /bin/getuid
# ls -la /bin/getuid
-r-sr-xr-x   1 root     root        6424 May 18 13:04 /bin/getuid
```

But it is not working as expected:

```
# su nobody -c /bin/getuid
60001
```

I expected a 0. Why is it not working?

Comment: I think the setuid bit just sets the euid. you have to all `setuid` in your program to change the uid of the program.

Comment: I think a better way of saying essentially the same thing is, "The setuid bit sets just the Effective UID (EUID).  You need to call `geteuid()` in your program to see that your EUID has changed."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this Q still-unanswered; [G-Man](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204053/how-to-run-a-setuid-program-on-solaris-10#comment343749_204053) and [Bratchley](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204053/how-to-run-a-setuid-program-on-solaris-10#comment343691_204053) have pointed out the error; `getuid()` returns the "real user ID of the calling process" while `geteuid()` returns the "effective user ID of the calling process".

You can see the difference with this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main (void) {
  printf ("getuid=%d, geteuid=%d\n", getuid(), geteuid());
  setuid(geteuid());
  printf ("getuid=%d, geteuid=%d\n", getuid(), geteuid());
}

$ gcc -o getuid getuid.c
$ sudo chown root getuid
$ sudo chmod u+s getuid
$ su nobody -c ./getuid
getuid=60001, geteuid=0
getuid=0, geteuid=0
```